# d3 Force Directed Graph General Update Pattern - exit() selection not working

Tags: d3.js

I'm having an with a force directed graph wherein my general update pattern does not seem to be working. Specifically when I try to update, unused nodes/links do not disappear as intended, and nodes/links that are still in the data do not transition to the new data. Instead, the old graph simply freezes and a new graph is drawn atop the old one.

I assume this is an issue with my selections not properly handling the data, but I've tried many tweaks and have not been able to figure out my issue. I have tried to follow [Bostock's example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1095795) as closely as possible, but it's not working as intended. [Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/brettasmi/pen/aKyGBv?editors=1000) with the visualization running (note: it's easiest to use the side-by-side editor to see the visualization).

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Updating Graph</title>
  <style>
    .links line {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }
    
    .nodes circle {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick=render(sp)>render new graph</button>
  <div class="chart"></div>
  <script>
    const cb = {
      "edges": [{
        "source": "a",
        "target": "b",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "a",
        "target": "c",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "b",
        "target": "c",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "c",
        "target": "d",
        "value": 1
      }],
      "nodes": [{
        "id": "a",
        "pop": 12.00328963067508,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "b",
        "pop": 12.391087593534877,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "c",
        "pop": 12.384324067681156,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "d",
        "pop": 13.991090521661292,
        "size": 6
      }]
    }
    const sp = {
      "edges": [{
        "source": "a",
        "target": "b",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "a",
        "target": "e",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "b",
        "target": "f",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "e",
        "target": "f",
        "value": 1
      }],
      "nodes": [{
        "id": "a",
        "pop": 12.00328963067508,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "b",
        "pop": 12.391087593534877,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "e",
        "pop": 13.063656176168433,
        "size": 6
      }, {
        "id": "f",
        "pop": 12.52608275807238,
        "size": 5
      }]
    }
    // set margins and canvas size
    const margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 30
    };
    const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // set up canvas
    const svg = d3.select('.chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .call(responsivefy)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    // set up selections
    let links = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line");
    let nodes = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle");

    // set up color scale
    const color = d3.scaleSequential()
      .domain([8, 15])
      .interpolator(d3.interpolateInferno);

    // set up simulation basic parameters
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    function render(graph) {
      // node selection and data handling
      let node = nodes
        .data(graph.nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // node general update pattern
      node.exit()
        .transition()
        .attr("r", 0)
        .remove();

      node = node
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
          return d.size;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d.pop);
        })
        .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended))
        .merge(node);
      // give all nodes a title with their id for hover identification
      node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // link selection, data handling
      let link = links
        .data(graph.edges, function(d) {
          return d.source + "-" + d.target;
        });

      // link general update pattern with attrTween to keep links connected to disappearing nodes
      link
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .attrTween("x1", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.source.x;
          };
        })
        .attrTween("x2", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.target.x;
          };
        })
        .attrTween("y1", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.source.y;
          };
        })
        .attrTween("y2", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.target.y;
          };
        })
        .remove();

      link = link
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
          return Math.sqrt(d.value);
        })
        .merge(link);

      // add nodes and links to the siumlation
      simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);
      simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.edges);
      // restart the simulation
      simulation.alpha(1).restart();

      // set the ticked function to constantly update node and link position
      function ticked() {
        link
          .attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
          });

        node
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
          });
      }
    };

    // initial render
    render(cb)

    // dragging functions
    function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }

    // responsivefy from https://brendansudol.com/writing/responsive-d3
    function responsivefy(svg) {
      // get container + svg aspect ratio
      const container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode),
        width = parseInt(svg.style("width")),
        height = parseInt(svg.style("height")),
        aspect = width / height;

      // add viewBox and preserveAspectRatio properties,
      // and call resize so that svg resizes on inital page load
      svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
        .call(resize);

      // to register multiple listeners for same event type,
      // you need to add namespace, i.e., 'click.foo'
      // necessary if you call invoke this function for multiple svgs
      // api docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on
      d3.select(window).on("resize." + container.attr("id"), resize);

      // get width of container and resize svg to fit it
      function resize() {
        const targetWidth = parseInt(container.style("width"));
        svg.attr("width", targetWidth);
        svg.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your selections `nodes` and `links` are empty selections:

```
// set up selections
let links = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line");
let nodes = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle");
```

As at this time there are no circles are lines, and D3 selections are immutable. This means that whenever you call `nodes.data()` or `links.data()` all items in the data array will be entered as there are no corresponding elements in the selection to update or exit - the selection remains empty (you could run nodes.size() each update to see this).

Instead, you could leave `links` and `nodes` as a selection of the parent `g`:

```
// set up selections
let links = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links");
let nodes = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes");
```

And select all links/nodes on each update:

```
let node = nodes.selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });
```

*(and the same for links)*

This way you will select any existing links/circles and be able to update/exit/enter as appropriate:

```js
 const cb = {
      "edges": [{
        "source": "a",
        "target": "b",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "a",
        "target": "c",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "b",
        "target": "c",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "c",
        "target": "d",
        "value": 1
      }],
      "nodes": [{
        "id": "a",
        "pop": 12.00328963067508,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "b",
        "pop": 12.391087593534877,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "c",
        "pop": 12.384324067681156,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "d",
        "pop": 13.991090521661292,
        "size": 6
      }]
    }
    const sp = {
      "edges": [{
        "source": "a",
        "target": "b",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "a",
        "target": "e",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "b",
        "target": "f",
        "value": 1
      }, {
        "source": "e",
        "target": "f",
        "value": 1
      }],
      "nodes": [{
        "id": "a",
        "pop": 12.00328963067508,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "b",
        "pop": 12.391087593534877,
        "size": 5
      }, {
        "id": "e",
        "pop": 13.063656176168433,
        "size": 6
      }, {
        "id": "f",
        "pop": 12.52608275807238,
        "size": 5
      }]
    }
    // set margins and canvas size
    const margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 30
    };
    const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // set up canvas
    const svg = d3.select('.chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .call(responsivefy)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    // set up selections
    let links = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links");
    let nodes = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes");

    // set up color scale
    const color = d3.scaleSequential()
      .domain([8, 15])
      .interpolator(d3.interpolateInferno);

    // set up simulation basic parameters
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    function render(graph) {
      // node selection and data handling
      let node = nodes.selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // node general update pattern
      node.exit()
        .transition()
        .attr("r", 0)
        .remove();

      node = node
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
          return d.size;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d.pop);
        })
        .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended))
        .merge(node);
      // give all nodes a title with their id for hover identification
      node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // link selection, data handling
      let link = links.selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.edges, function(d) {
          return d.source + "-" + d.target;
        });

      // link general update pattern with attrTween to keep links connected to disappearing nodes
      link
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .attrTween("x1", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.source.x;
          };
        })
        .attrTween("x2", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.target.x;
          };
        })
        .attrTween("y1", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.source.y;
          };
        })
        .attrTween("y2", function(d) {
          return function() {
            return d.target.y;
          };
        })
        .remove();

      link = link
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
          return Math.sqrt(d.value);
        })
        .merge(link);

      // add nodes and links to the siumlation
      simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);
      simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.edges);
      // restart the simulation
      simulation.alpha(1).restart();

      // set the ticked function to constantly update node and link position
      function ticked() {
        link
          .attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
          });

        node
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
          });
      }
    };

    // initial render
    render(cb)

    // dragging functions
    function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }

    // responsivefy from https://brendansudol.com/writing/responsive-d3
    function responsivefy(svg) {
      // get container + svg aspect ratio
      const container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode),
        width = parseInt(svg.style("width")),
        height = parseInt(svg.style("height")),
        aspect = width / height;

      // add viewBox and preserveAspectRatio properties,
      // and call resize so that svg resizes on inital page load
      svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
        .call(resize);

      // to register multiple listeners for same event type,
      // you need to add namespace, i.e., 'click.foo'
      // necessary if you call invoke this function for multiple svgs
      // api docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on
      d3.select(window).on("resize." + container.attr("id"), resize);

      // get width of container and resize svg to fit it
      function resize() {
        const targetWidth = parseInt(container.style("width"));
        svg.attr("width", targetWidth);
        svg.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
      }
    }
```

```css
    .links line {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }
    
    .nodes circle {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  <button onclick=render(sp)>render new graph</button>
  <div class="chart"></div>
```

Or, updated [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEoxyG)

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I made the selections like that following Bostock's example that I linked in the original post. Do you have any insight why those selections aren't empty? My guess is that he starts the simulation before defining the selections, but I'm not very confident in that. Thanks again Andrew.

Comment: Ah, his original selection is `node`, where yours is `nodes`, but you both merge the enter selection with `node` - so Mike is redefining his original selection, and your were merging to a temporary selection recreated on each update.

Comment: You would need to rename all incidences of the variable names `links` to `link` and `nodes` to `node` or vice versa for Mike's approach to work: [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KevJPK?editors=1000), this way you redefine the original selection as the merged selection on the update.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I can't recall my reason for naming the original selection something else. One final question, though feel free to tell me to make a new post, but do you know how to get my nodes to transition smoothly to their new locations? I've updated the original [pen here](https://codepen.io/brettasmi/pen/aKyGBv?editors=1011) with very slow transitions to demonstrate the jumpiness of the nodes.

Comment: That might have to be a separate question - an interesting and as far as I know novel one. From what I see you have two functions competing for positioning: the force tick and the transition, and both are running simultaneously after updating. You could interpolate between both of those perhaps (complicated a little by the drag potentially as well).